# How to get response from server in MQ system (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, zeromq, python-asyncio, pyzmq

I would like to make a chatting room server between chatting room user clients.
The system server have to send all utterances to translator and wait the response result.
I made this system with async web socket library.
How can I deal with this waiting part from translator, if I change to async MQ system.

client <- server -> translator server

So now, I made a thread for waiting translator's response.

```
def _run(self, send_to_client):
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.listening_handler(send_to_client))

def run(self, send_to_client):
    self.thread_run_flag = True
    thread = Thread(target=self._run, args=(send_to_client,))
    thread.start()
    return thread

async def listening_handler(self, send_to_client):
    while True:
        data = await reader.read()
            if not data:
                continue
            await send_to_client(data)
```

1. Is this a right way?
2. If I want to use a single thread with MQ system, how can I change this structure?